# Prove $\theta:V\rightarrow V^*$, $A\rightarrow f_A$ is a isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ y for all $A\in V$ consider 
$f_A:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. such that $f_A(B)=tr(AB)$

Prove $\theta:V\rightarrow V^*$, $A\rightarrow f_A$ is a isomorphism of vector spaces

Note: $V^*=\{f|f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{K}\}$

My work:

For prove $\theta$ is isomorphism we need to prove $\theta$ is injective and surjective.

**Injectivity**

Suppose $\theta (A)=\theta (B)$

Then for $Z\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

$f_A(Z)=f_B(Z) \implies tr(AZ)=tr(BZ)\implies tr(AZ)-tr(BZ)=0\implies tr(AZ-BZ)=0\implies tr((A-B)Z)=0$

here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that it is injective, since $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension.

Suppose that $f_A$ is zero. Then in particular $f_A(A^T)=0$. So $\mathrm{tr}(AA^T)=0$, and hence $A=0$ (since $\mathrm{tr}(AA^T)=\sum\limits_{i,j}a_{i,j}^2).$

---

As a sidenote,
$(A,B) \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(A^TB)$ is an inner product on the space of matrices. Your map is then just the composition
$$V \to V \to  V^*;$$
$$A \mapsto A^T \mapsto\langle A^T,  \cdot\rangle,$$
which is the composition of the Riesz representation and an involution, both isomorphisms. It may be instructive to compare how this relates to the proof I gave above.

Comment: Thanks Aloizio! Very clear. One question, how do you see $V$ and $V^*$ have de same dimension?

Comment: You prove $Ker(f_a)$ is $0$ no?

Comment: @Bvss12 You can see that $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension by fixing a basis for $V$ and considering its so-called "dual basis" (but you don't know that it is a basis yet :P) in $V^*$, then you can show that it is a basis there.

Comment: @Bvss12 The argument above (in the answer itself) shows that the map $A \mapsto f_A$ has kernel $0$ (I took an $A$ and, assuming that $f_A$ is the zero functional, I arrived at the fact that $A=0$), hence is injective.